# Why don't we commonly solve partial differential equations with sums of functions, instead of products?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It's very common to solve partial differential equations via "separable solution", in the following way. Say we have the wave equation,

$$u_t=u_{xx}.$$

We often solve this by assuming a form $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, which gives

$$\frac{T_t}{T}=\frac{X_{xx}}{X}=\lambda,$$

where $\lambda$ is the separation constant, and the final solution looks something like

$$u(x,t)=C\exp (\lambda t -i\sqrt{\lambda} x)$$

However, it seems to me we could just as easily have tried the ansatz $u(x,t)=X(x)+T(t)$. Then our PDE would look like

$$T_t=X_{xx}=\lambda$$

And we would find

$$X(x)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda x^2 + C_2 x + C_3,\qquad T(t)=\lambda t + C_1.$$

Basically, a polynomial solution instead of an exponential one.

Is there any good reason why we often present the first way instead of the second? I guess there are "niceness" properties that the exponentials have, but polynomial solutions are nice in some ways too.

Comment: You can find some solutions this way, but the collection of solutions you find by assuming separability is somehow much more rich. By taking linear combinations of the separable solutions, you can construct a solution that satisfies any given initial and boundary conditions.

Comment: @littleO: it's not that I disagree with that basic sentiment, but polynomials are very generic as well, right? I guess the argument is that exponentials are infinite polynomials (in some convergence radius), and are therefore more generic then finite polynomials. Still seems imprecise to me. Maybe I need an example where the usual separability is clearly advantageous?

Comment: @littleO Maybe make that an answer?

Comment: Just try to solve a generic initial-boundary value problem. You'll see that you can't do it using only those simple polynomial solutions.

Comment: @littleO: Well, I guess for sure you need to specify more boundary conditions, since there are more constants. A stupid example might be $u(0,0)=u_1=C_1+C_3$, $u_x(0,0)=u_2=C_2$, $u_t(0,0)=u_3=\lambda$, leaving e.g. $C_1$ unset, as $u_{xx}(0,0)=\lambda$ again.

Comment: A typical initial boundary value problem (IBVP) for the heat equation is to find a continuous function u(x,t) that satisfies $u_t = u_{xx}$ on $(a,b) \times (0,\infty)$ as well as $u(a,t) = u(b,t) = 0$ for all $t > 0$ and $u(x,0) = f(x)$ for all $a \leq x \leq b$. Here $f$ is a given function. Have you learned how to solve this type of IBVP? If not, I recommend going ahead and learning. You'll see the role played by the separable solutions that we have found.

Comment: By the way, I do think this is a great question you are asking. Perfect example of "Don't just read it, fight it!"

Comment: @littleO: Yeah look at what happens to your specific solution on my "dumb" one: your $f(x)=X(x)$, and $T(0)=0$ sets $C_1=0$. However, that means $f(x)$ must solve $f''=\lambda f$, and it is no longer an arbitrary given function (it must be harmonic). So that's more about restricting the kinds of problems one can solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collection of solutions you find by assuming separability is much richer than the collection of simple polynomial solutions you find by taking $u(x,t) = X(x) + T(t)$. In particular, by taking linear combinations of separable solutions, we can solve any given initial-boundary value problem (IBVP) for the heat equation.

I'll show how this works out in detail. The following material can be found in PDE textbooks such as Boyce and DiPrima.

For example, consider the following IBVP: Find a continuous function $u: [0,1] \times [0,\infty)$ such that $u$ satisfies the heat equation $u_t = u_{xx}$ on $\Omega = (0,1) \times (0,\infty)$ as well as the boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$ (for all $t > 0$) and the initial condition $u(x,0) = f(x)$. Here $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is any given continuous, piecewise differentiable function that satisfies $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. (Other assumptions on $f$ are also possible, but the restrictions on $f$ are always very mild.)

First we find separable solutions to the heat equation which satisfy the given boundary conditions. If a separable function $u(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$ satisfies the heat equation on $\Omega$, then there must exist a constant $\lambda$ such that 
$$
T'(t)/T(t) = X''(x)/X(x) = \lambda
$$
for all $(x,t) \in \Omega$. If $\lambda$ were positive, our boundary conditions could not be satisfied. If $\lambda = 0$ then $u(x,t) = 0$, a trivial solution. So we assume that $\lambda$ is negative.
It follows that $T(t) = T_0 e^{\lambda t}$ and $X(x) = a \cos(\sqrt{-\lambda} x) + b \sin(\sqrt{-\lambda} x)$
for some constants $T_0, a$, and $b$. Now plugging in the boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$, we find that $a = 0$ and $b \sin(\sqrt{-\lambda}) = 0$.
Assuming that $b \neq 0$, it follows that $\sqrt{-\lambda} = n \pi$ for some positive integer $n$. So the separable solutions we have found are
$$
u_n(x,t) = c e^{- n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n \pi x) \quad \text{for } n = 1, 2, \ldots.
$$

Now we solve the IBVP given above by seeking a solution of the form
$$
u(x,t) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty c_n e^{-n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n \pi x).
$$
This $u$ automatically satisfies $u_t = u_{xx}$ as well as $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$ for all $t > 0$. The only issue is to make $u$ satisfy the initial condition
$$
u(x,0) = f(x).
$$
This initial condition can only be satisfied if there exist constants $c_n$ (for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$) such that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \sin(n \pi x).
$$
Now here is the amazing part: it turns out that *any* function $f$ satisfying the above conditions can be represented like this! That is a fact from Fourier analysis. Fourier made this claim, optimistically, but no one believed him at first. If I understand the history correctly, this is the thought process that led to the discovery of Fourier series --- a momentous moment in the history of math. Why math tends to work out so nicely is a deep mystery, a glimpse of perfection in the universe.

So by taking linear combinations of the separable functions we are able to solve our IBVP. This wouldn't have worked if we had tried to find a solution $u$ that is a linear combination of the simple polynomial solutions mentioned in the question. In particular, the step where we have to represent $f$ would have failed.

Answer (score 1):

Partial differential equations (PDEs) differ from ordinary differential equations (ODEs) that involve functions of only one variable. However, this difference makes PDEs appreciably more difficult to solve. In fact, the vast majority of PDE cannot be solved analytically and those classes of special PDEs that can be solved analytically invariably involve converting the PDE into one or more ODEs and then solving independently. One of these approaches is *the method of separation of variables*  or, *Fourier's method* or, *product rule* or, *the method of eigenfunction expansion*. It is one of the most widely used techniques to solve partial differential equations and is based on the assumption that the solution of the equation is separable, that is, the final solution can be represented as a product of several functions, each of which is only dependent upon a single independent variable. Daniel Bernoulli invented this technique in the $1700$s. We do not know the actual reason behind the ansatz i.e.,  why we have to choose the form of the method of separation of variables as $~u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)~$. But it works good. If this assumption is incorrect, then clear violations of mathematical principles will be obvious from the analysis.

The method of separation of variables is used when the partial differential equation
and the boundary conditions are linear and homogeneous. The advantage of the product method is that it transforms a partial differential equation, which we do not know how to solve, into two ordinary differential equations.

You may also see [What is the motivation behind a product solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776245/what-is-the-motivation-behind-a-product-solution)

Comment: Well, all this information seems great, but when you say "The advantage of the product method is that it transforms a partial differential equation [...] into two ordinary differential equations. ", I want to point out that sum of functions can do that as well (see my original example with the wave equation).

Comment: Actually the form $~u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)~$ for the method of separation of variables is a special one. We take it as a trivial solution for the given PDE. The solution in general should satisfy certain additional conditions. In many cases, these
additional conditions are just homogeneous boundary conditions (you skip this important point in your question). If you choose the form proposed by Bernoulli i.e., the product form then the calculation is easy due to the additional boundary conditions.

Comment: But in the form proposed by you the calculation will be more laborious after your solution satisfies the additional boundary conditions [think about it]. We always preferred to solve problems with minimum effort.

Comment: In this regard, I also want to mention that this special form(product form) of  the method of separation of variables is an **ansatz** proposed by Bernoulli to solve the PDE.